# usb wifi adapter driver installation

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, software-installation

I need help for driver installation for usb wifi adapter "Laptone N600" on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I downloaded driver from Laptone site and from Mediatek site. I tried `lsusb` and got:

```
ID 0e8d:7610 Mediatek
```

I'm a beginner and really I don't know what to do. Can someone give me help?

Answer (score 0):

With a temporary working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u.git
cd mt7610u
make
sudo make install
sudo cp firmware/*  /lib/firmware
sudo insmod mt7610u.ko
```

Please tell us how it went as we will have additional steps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation and all comments here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51532/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-usb-wifi-adapter-driver-installation).